# Java Regex format String

Tags: java, regex, string, ocr

I'm new in Java and regex. I'm trying to extract data from the following string:

```
JAMMURI YA KENYA ¢)a(s REPUBLIC OF KENYA
sennc wnecs: 23085129 aShl e 31662252
FULL NAMES
JUDITH AWINO OWITI
DATE OF BIRTH
25. 10. 1992
SEX
FEMALE
DISTRICT OF BIRTH
MUHORONI
PLACE OF ISSUE
. NYANDO
DATE OF ISSUE
' 16.04. 2013 A
j HOLDER'S SIGN oo - Ve
```

Where: `23085129 = IDNumber, 31662252 = SerialNumber, JUDITH AWINO OWITI = Name, 25. 10. 1992 = DateOfBirth`

Here is my code:

```
static HashMap<String, String> interpretText(String ocrText) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        result.put("Text", ocrText);

        for (String text : ocrText.split("\\r?\\n")) {      
            //Get ID Only
            String pattern = "\\s+([0-9]{9})";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("IDNumber: " + m.group(0) );
                result.put("IDNumber", m.group(0));
            }

            // Get all other numbers
            pattern  = "(\\d+)(.*)";
            r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            m = r.matcher(text);
            if (m.find()) {
                 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

My challenge is how to extract the above mentioned key data items from the string. My regex implementation does not work. What is the right regex implementation for `23085129 = IDNumber, 31662252 = SerialNumber, JUDITH AWINO OWITI = Name, 25. 10. 1992 = DateOfBirth` within the loop?

Comment: You could just use a single pattern: `[^\n]+\n[^\n\d]+(\d+)[^\n\d]+(\d+)\nFULL NAMES\n([^\n]+)\nDATE OF BIRTH\n([^\n]+)` where `matcher.group(1)` is the IDNumber, `2` is the `SerialNumber`, `3` is the `Name` and `4` the `DateOfBirth`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMsbJN/1)

Comment: Thank you for the assist. It works well. That is pretty smooth. Regards.

Comment: [`(?m:^)sennc wnecs: (?<IDNumber>\d+) aShl e (?<SerialNumber>\d+)\RFULL NAMES\R(?<Name>.*)\RDATE OF BIRTH\R(?<DateOfBirth>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lLdVwa/1)

Comment: @CheruiyotFelix Are these strings always there? `sennc wnecs:` and  `aShl e` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird No - they might be different. This is an OCR output. The results might omit some of them. I can somehow rely on the lines/number of lines to extract the right information.

Comment: Perhaps this would also work to prevent empty matches `^.*?: (\d+)\D+(\d+)\RFULL NAMES\R(\S.*)\RDATE OF BIRTH\R(\d.*)` https://regex101.com/r/eLdgQD/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird - I'll give it a try as I scan more data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(?:.*)\s(\d+)[\w\s]+\s(\d+)\WFULL NAMES\W([\w\s]+)\WDATE OF BIRTH\W([\d.\s]+)
```

Here you can see how it works: https://regexr.com/51f5v

Java example:

```java
String data = "JAMMURI YA KENYA ¢)a(s REPUBLIC OF KENYA\n" +
        "sennc wnecs: 23085129 aShl e 31662252\n" +
        "FULL NAMES\n" +
        "JUDITH AWINO OWITI\n" +
        "DATE OF BIRTH\n" +
        "25. 10. 1992\n" +
        "SEX\n" +
        "FEMALE\n" +
        "DISTRICT OF BIRTH\n" +
        "MUHORONI\n" +
        "PLACE OF ISSUE\n" +
        ". NYANDO\n" +
        "DATE OF ISSUE\n" +
        "' 16.04. 2013 A\n" +
        "j HOLDER'S SIGN oo - Ve";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:.*)\\s(\\d+)[\\w\\s]+\\s(\\d+)\\WFULL NAMES\\W([\\w\\s]+)\\WDATE OF BIRTH\\W([\\d.\\s]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("IDNumber: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("SerialNumber: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("DateOfBirth: " + matcher.group(4));
}
```

Output:

```
IDNumber: 23085129
SerialNumber: 31662252
Name: JUDITH AWINO OWITI
DateOfBirth: 25. 10. 1992
```